# Java. MongoDB. Sort sub document after unwind

Tags: java, mongodb

I have users, and skills into the user.

```
[
{
    "_id": "5b91668a0f77e30c11574c88",
    "full_name": "John Smith"
    "skills": [
        {
            "_id": "61966603ceb6da478418aac0",
            "name": "Java",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "61966533ceb6da4092707441",
            "name": "Scala",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "619f9dce86b62c370e1c5fcc",
            "name": "MongoDB",
            "active": true
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I need to get all user skills in A-Z order by name. I found many solutions, but they are all for MongoDB. I am trying to use the functions of the class `com.mongodb.client.model.Agregate`, but sorting doesn't work for me (returns in a different order, but it is not clear in what order.) and I do not understand why. Maybe I am do something wrong, or exist another implementation of my task?

```
var result = getCollection().aggregate(
    asList(
            match(eq("_id", userId)),
            unwind("$skills"),
            sort(ascending("skills.name")),
            group(null, addToSet("skills", "$skills"))),
    Document.class);
```

Comment: When you say `I need to get all user skills in A-Z order by name` what output do you seek?  Especially grouped by ... what.   Show us a desired output document.

Comment: Try using `push` instead of `addToSet` - and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can altogether avoid the `$unwind`, `$sort` and `$group` stages, and use the following aggregation `$addFileds`  (or `$project`) stage to sort the array elements. This uses the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) aggregate expression (MongoDB v4.4).

Consider an input document:

```
{ 
  skills: [ { name: "Java" }, { name: "Scala" }, { name: "Mongo" }, { name: "Groovy" } ] 
}
```

The query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          skills: {
              $function: {
                  body: function(input) {
                      const sorter = function(x1, x2) {
                                               if (x1.name > x2.name) { 
                                                   return 1; 
                                               } 
                                               else if (x2.name > x1.name) { 
                                                   return -1; 
                                               } 
                                               else { 
                                                   return 0; 
                                               };
                      };
                      input.sort(sorter);
                      return input;
                  },
                  args: [ "$skills" ],
                  lang: "js"
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

The output with sorted `skills` array (by `name` field):

```
skills: [ { name: "Groovy" }, { name: "Java" }, { name: "Mongo" }, { name: "Scala" } ]
```