# Mongoose how to sort by field on an object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose schema looks like the following . How do I sort by the created at field on the images? I've tried the following query, but it does not work. I'm not sure how to deal with the array of objects.

```
imageData = await User.find({'_id': {$in: followingIdArr}}).select('images -_id').sort({createdAt: -1})

 const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please enter a username"],
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: [6, "Minimum password length is 6 characters"]
    },
    followers: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    followings: {
        type: Array,
        defaul: []
    },
    profilePicture: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
        maxlength: 50
    },
    images: {
        type: [{id: String, url: String, description: String, likes: [], createdAt: String,}],

    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
```

);

Comment: can you please add some example data?

Comment: If you are using MongoDB v5.2+, you can use the `$sortArray`. Or, you can use the `$function` for sorting the array (an example SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116607/java-mongodb-sort-sub-document-after-unwind/70120022#70120022).

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Mongodb 4.81. I don't see any npm package with version > 4.81. How do I upgrade to v5.2+? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help to you. !

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$in": [
          "62e80dbeba5e390027c0059f"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "images": {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$images",
          sortBy: {
            "createdAt": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I have added example in this link:- https://mongoplayground.net/p/QNiMS2krTro